# How do I control a fan attached to GPIO pins on Android?

Tags: gpio, pi-4, android

I installed android tv with konstakang on my Raspberry pi 4 device. While using linux with GPIO pins, I made fan control with python according to temperature.

How can I use GPIO fans on Android?

Comment: Note that python isn't directly supported on Android, although I believe there are tools which can convert scripts to .apk's.

Comment: I solved this problem. I used DToverlay. I tried auto fan control by editing the config.txt and with the following command. I no longer need to use GPIO on the Android side.


"dtoverlay=gpio-fan, dtoverlay=rpi-poe"

Comment: Please post that here as an answer for posterity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. I used DToverlay. I tried auto fan control by editing the config.txt and with the following command. I no longer need to use GPIO on the Android side.

```
dtoverlay=gpio-fan, dtoverlay=rpi-poe
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Raspcontroller, it is in the Play Store.
https://www.gallinaettore.com/android_apps/raspcontroller/

Comment: That's an android app for remote access.  The OP has installed Android *on a Pi 4*.